# Advanced Installer error on running MySQL script at Program Setup

Tags: mysql, advanced-installer

I have this Visual Studio program that I am packaging into an .exe setup using Advanced Installer v10.7. I have added all the prerequisites into the installer with no issues.

My problem comes in when I am trying to run a MySQL script I included in the installer. 
I created the script using SQLyog Backup DataBase As SQL Dump.

I have made sure that the correct version of MySQL is installed on the target computer. During the install process, I get the error

[image]

This is the part of the script that is throwing the error from the Advanced Installer - SQL Scripts page

[image]

What I don't understand is that when I try to restore my database directly form SQLyog using the same script, it works.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to set ';' as a statement separator? option available below the inline script

Comment: Thats it! You should put is as the answer Bogdan Mitrache. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that there is no statement separator specified. Try setting that field (visible below the inline script field) to ';'.

Comment: Wouldn't have guessed that. Hope this helps other users with the same problem.